# How to include the BPM in Clip packs

Tags: ableton-live

In Ableton you can put clips into multiple scenes and if you highlight them all and drag to a folder they will be saved as a clip pack, then you can select clip packs and drag them over to to play them. The previous 32 bit version would also save the BPM for each clip pack so that when I drag a new pack over it would automatically play at the correct BPM. I recently changed from 32 bit to 64, now this no longer works. With this version the BPM stays at the previous packs BPM. If I right click on the BPM box a sub menu appears with the option to return to default (120 BPM). If I do that before I load the new clip it will then change the BPM correctly when I load the new clip, but I never had to do that before. 
 It makes no difference if I rename the master column because it is not saved with the clip pack. I know the BPM information is contained within the clip pack because if I double click on one it will open to the correct BPM, but no longer by dragging and dropping unless I set it back to default. I need to use the drag and drop method because I have a template set up with all the other effects and plugins that would take way to long to load in a live setting. My question is what has changed between the 2 versions and is there a setting i can change to make this work again?